# Connect Epic medical system from mobile app

Tags: rest, epic

Recently I read Open Epic API.We have a mobile App that just keep users and their family's health records.
Now some of our clients need to share this data to their Epic EHR .I think it is possible to use Epic web services to insert a user records to epic from a 3rd party app.But I did'nt find any more documentation regarding this.

My Questions are here

1)Is it possible to update a a users basic health records from our app to Epic using Open epic web service ?

2)From where i get the Web service documentations ?details like API endpoint , parameters , return types etc

3)What all details i need to connect to an epic account through web service?

Help is highly appreciable,
Thanks,

Comment: Still no answer to this Q? Is there any paid APIs ? any references/docs available ? I found this https://open.epic.com/Interface/WebServices only